# How to exploit a windows server when you have read-only filesystem access

Tags: windows, exploit

I found a vulnerability in a site that can allow the download of any file of the server. I tested it by succesfully downloading `boot.ini` and `autoexec.bat`.

I have no access to source code or file system structures. All I know is it runs Win 2003 Server Ent. in drive `C:`, Oracle 10.1.2 AS_1 in drive `F:`.

I would like to know what files can be downloaded in order to compromise it? (I dont have the intention of doing aything wrong in this server, just want to know how vulnerable it is.)

I suspect that I can use this vulnerability to escalate to shell access, or at least write access of some kind. Are there files containing credentials that may be used for a remote login, for example? What files should I try downloading next?

(Conversely, these are the files that the administrator must take care to protect. If you were the system administrator, which files' permissions would you double check before declaring the server ready to go live?)

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean *download* (getting files from the server) or *upload* (sending files to the server)?

Comment: I mean getting files from the server

Comment: @ponsfonze Yes, but you can't compromise a server by downloading files.  You can use the information gathered from downloads to plan your attack, but downloading in and of itself will not do anything to the system.  The worst you might try to do is DoS it by running a whole lot of concurrent downloads.  Downloading is effectively useless to compromise a system except as a means of information gathering.

Comment: Uploading files, on the other hand, can do quite a bit of damage if you have access to write to certain areas of the system and/or overwrite critical system files.

Comment: look for database files to download, you'll have to set up an equivalent database daemon yourself, unless you feel like trawling through raw database info in a hex editor. if the server runs a website, it will certainly have a database somewhere, which will probably contain password hashes.

Comment: @lynks It's really hard to "look for" anything when he has "no access to the source code or file system structures".

Comment: @Iszi i dont know much about windows, but on linux just take a peek in /var/lib/mysql for all the raw database info.

Comment: @Iszi I read the question as, what files contain information that is likely to lead to a way to run arbitrary code? E.g. find a remote login service and find the file that contains its password database, then brute-force a password. For example, `/etc/shadow` under Linux, if there is a remote login service that accepts passwords.

Comment: I have to downvote the question for the simple fact a person who actually didn't want to cause harm to the server in question would not be looking for ways to actually compromise the server.

Answer (score 2):

You already have your answer. It is very vulnerable to LFI because someone can download system files. You have already compromised the system.

You can use brute-force techniques to map out the file structure.

If, instead, you want shell access, then you need to download configuration files to determine what services might be running and how they are configured, then log in using those services. Or else find a way to upload a shell to the server.

Oh, and I call "blackhat" ....